# Can we rename "Ask question"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

A [recent "question"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83478/why-can-not-transfer-file-0-bytesthanks) (will probably be deleted when you click it) made me realize: The "Ask Question" label on Code Review can be a bit misleading here.

Code Review questions are expected to contain real, reviewable code. Is it possible to rename the "Ask Question" label to "*Post code for review*" or similar?

This is essentially a three-part meta question:

1. Is it *possible* to rename the "Ask Question" label?
2. *Should* we rename the "Ask Question" label?
3. *What* should we rename the "Ask Question" label *to*?

Comment: If "Ask a question" were renamed, would Code Review not be eliminated as a Stack Exchange site?  The Stack Exchange network is a collection of **question** and answer sites.

Comment: @nhgrif  We already made that change.  Instead of questions, our titles are descriptions.  Instead of answers, we provide reviews.  This would just make the interface match site policy.

Comment: As to question 3, perhaps "Ask for Review" would work, and not be too far from the current text. Good luck getting the SE devs to implement that, though, especially for a site still in beta (and thus not having a separate design of its own). Ps. If you do manage to pull this off, [codegolf.SE] is going to want one too. ;)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Technically, Code Review has graduated. We're just in the waiting queue for a design and stuff to come along.

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/597/why-are-they-questions-if-this-site-is-primarily-for-code-review-requests related.

Answer (score 15):

I think if it's possible, we definitely should. Unlike other stack exchange sites the posts made here aren't really questions, at least not by the primary definition of the term. Which I agree is somewhat misleading.

Although posts may contain a question, more often than not when the main objective is asking a question, it's off-topic. I personally use this idea to scan for new posts containing question marks, most of the time they need to be reviewed/closed.

Comment: Actually the question part is what does the review want primarily reviewed.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Exchange is a network of question-and-answer sites.  Code Review is one, too — it says so on our [tour page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Should we rename the "Ask Question" link?  I don't think so, at least not as a reaction to one very confused user among the thousands of happy customers.  Anything else would be inconsistent, not as succinct, and could make things worse.  For example, if we rename it to "Post Code For Review", then we would start blaming the wording for code-dump questions.

The *name* of the site is *Code Review*, and if that isn't enough of a hint that the question should include code, then I'm not sure that changing a label will do anything.

We do have a problem with too many off-topic questions being posted, but that is mostly because the posted code doesn't work, or is hypothetical.  That's quite a different problem, and not something that would be addressed by this proposal.

Comment: It is absolutely not intended as a *reaction* to the post mentioned, it was just what was inspired the idea.

Comment: I agree we shouldn't rename just because of 1 confused user. But "Ask Question" simply "feels wrong" when I'm actually not asking a question but posting code for review. "Post Code for Review" would feel more appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

1. It looks like we could.  For example, here's the Ask Question button for Arqade (gaming):  http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/mothership.png?v=6ceca251c5e2  Since it's possible to customize that button, we should be able to put our own text in the image.  Also, if you look at the Portuguese version of Stack Overflow, they actually have different text there (without a button image).  So it would seem to be possible.  I wouldn't be surprised if the button were easier than changing the text, but that's really a StackExchange question.  Note that this doesn't change the link in either case.
2. I could go either way.  I don't know that it would help much, but it might.  It would probably mostly help with those from other StackExchange sites where the rules are different.  It might hint to them that this site is different and they should read the help to understand why/how.
3. I have a couple suggestions for alternatives:  "Post Review Request" or simply "Request Review".

Either of those would be sufficiently different from the other Stack Exchange sites to make people more likely to think that we are different.  Neither mentions code, so they shouldn't encourage code dumps any more than the existing system.

To avoid confusion, I think that votes for [Legato's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5112/53820) should represent votes for changing the text.

Votes for this answer should mean that if the text gets changed, we choose either Post Review Request or Request Review.

Answer (score 6):

I think that no matter what we call it, people will still be inclined to post their code dump or verbatim homework question.  When it comes to those who will not take three seconds to read some text, there's no way to win.  Heck, even on SO, people click that button and don't even ask a question!  To them, it's probably more of a "post concern" button.

Slight ranting aside, I don't think it'll solve our problem, plus it'll just give SE even more headaches.  Just as with any other site, we just have to communicate the site's intentions, even for those not wanting to read about them at first.  If it also means more downvotes, then so be it.  That's why we have them.

Comment: I don't expect it to magically solve our entire "problem". I am however expecting it to reduce the number of off-topic questions.